# Swift: Sort Array by sort descriptors

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, core-data, swift

I am using coredata so I need sort descriptors for my entities

For example, a Coordinate-entity has this class func:

```
class func sortDescriptors() -> Array<NSSortDescriptor>
{
    return [NSSortDescriptor(key: "sequence", ascending: true)]
}
```

I am using this when doing fetch-requests to CoreData like this:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)

request.sortDescriptors = T.sortDescriptors()
```

However, when I have an array of coordinates as a property on another coredata object, this is an NSSet (I.e. unsorted)

To solve this, I am returning the coordinates like this:

```
return NSArray(array: coordinates!).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(Coordinate.sortDescriptors()) as? Array<Coordinate>
```

Which feels ugly, to use an NSArray just to get the `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`-method. Is there a similar way to do this directly on a Swift-array, I.e. `Array<Coordinate>` by using sort descriptors?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use `NSSet`'s `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors()` method?

Comment: I could do that aswell! But the question still stands; is sort sescriptors compatible with Swift-arrays?

Comment: @rintaro `NSSet` instances are unordered by definition. I assume that you are referring to `NSArray`.

Answer (score 21):

Another approach to the nice extensions of Damien could be a multi-cast.

```
myArray = (myArray as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors(tableView.sortDescriptors) as! Array
```

Original source: [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nssortdescriptor/)

Answer (score 10):

There is no built-in method for this, but you can add them using protocol extension:

```
extension MutableCollectionType where Index : RandomAccessIndexType, Generator.Element : AnyObject {
    /// Sort `self` in-place using criteria stored in a NSSortDescriptors array
    public mutating func sortInPlace(sortDescriptors theSortDescs: [NSSortDescriptor]) {
        sortInPlace {
            for sortDesc in theSortDescs {
                switch sortDesc.compareObject($0, toObject: $1) {
                case .OrderedAscending: return true
                case .OrderedDescending: return false
                case .OrderedSame: continue
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}

extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : AnyObject {
    /// Return an `Array` containing the sorted elements of `source`
    /// using criteria stored in a NSSortDescriptors array.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func sort(sortDescriptors theSortDescs: [NSSortDescriptor]) -> [Self.Generator.Element] {
        return sort {
            for sortDesc in theSortDescs {
                switch sortDesc.compareObject($0, toObject: $1) {
                case .OrderedAscending: return true
                case .OrderedDescending: return false
                case .OrderedSame: continue
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

But note that this will work only when the array elements are classes, not structures, as NSSortDescriptor compareObject method requires arguments conforming to AnyObject

Comment: Big kudos to you! This was a mind-freaking issue for me. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 Version of @Darniel's answer

```
extension MutableCollection where Self : RandomAccessCollection {
    /// Sort `self` in-place using criteria stored in a NSSortDescriptors array
    public mutating func sort(sortDescriptors theSortDescs: [NSSortDescriptor]) {
        sort { by:
            for sortDesc in theSortDescs {
                switch sortDesc.compare($0, to: $1) {
                case .orderedAscending: return true
                case .orderedDescending: return false
                case .orderedSame: continue
                }
            }
            return false
        }

    }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : AnyObject {
    /// Return an `Array` containing the sorted elements of `source`
    /// using criteria stored in a NSSortDescriptors array.

    public func sorted(sortDescriptors theSortDescs: [NSSortDescriptor]) -> [Self.Iterator.Element] {
        return sorted {
            for sortDesc in theSortDescs {
                switch sortDesc.compare($0, to: $1) {
                case .orderedAscending: return true
                case .orderedDescending: return false
                case .orderedSame: continue
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```